# When are python imports loaded in memory?

Tags: python, import, python-import

From earlier questions on SO like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084487/why-lazy-import-is-not-default-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58216733/python-lazy-import-of-modules), it seems that the simple `import` keyword does not do lazy loading of modules. However, when I run a simple test to check the memory usage before and after the `import` statement - it seems that some modules are indeed loaded lazily.

Example:

```
>>> import django

>>> from django.http import HttpResponse
```

Memory Usage (the first `free` command is run after the first import and the second `free` command is run after the second import above):

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3935        1773         399           0        1762        1889

$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3935        1787         386           0        1762        1875
```

**Note** the increase in used memory from 1773MB to 1787MB.

I am trying to understand when does a module actually get loaded in memory? And why does an `import django` command not load all of django modules in memory?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I was expecting that `import django` would indeed load all of the modules within django. But as pointed out in the answer by @Ron Serruya, it seems like the django init file doesn't load those modules, so it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `import some_pgk` do is to run the `some_pkg.__init__` file

This is the init file for django

```py
from django.utils.version import get_version

VERSION = (4, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0)

__version__ = get_version(VERSION)


def setup(set_prefix=True):
    ...
    ...
```

As you can see it doesn't do much, it only sets the version, this is why other modules (such as django.http) don't get importer when running `import django`

Answer (score 4):

> it seems that the simple import keyword does not do lazy loading of modules.

How should it? `import` has to guarantee the code in the imported file / module's `__init__.py` is executed at the point of importing.

Just try the following: make a file `test.py`, containing nothing but `print("hey!")`, and in the same directory, `import .test`. You'll notice that import really isn't different from just executing the code in `test.py`.

> I am trying to understand when does a module actually get loaded in memory?

`import name` really just executes the specified code in the current namespace under the `name` namespace. If you define a class in that code, then its instantly visible, has to get parsed, and whatnot.

> And why does an import django command not load all of django modules in memory?

Because the code that gets executed on `import django` simply doesn't do that. (just as it doesn't get up and make us the much-deserved coffee!)

Comment: I see. Then, it's dependent on the module that I am using. If, for example, django were to load all of its modules in the import statement then they would have got loaded in memory.

Comment: exactly, that's the case.